# local.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Process could not be started [El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada. ]

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una página web laravel que mediante una ruta envía un formulario, esa ruta llama a un controlador y el controlador se encarga de envíar el Mail de contacto. La cuestión es que este proceso funciona perfectamente en un hosting, el problema es cuando quiero ejecutarlo de manera local, me aparece el siguiente error. Probé con volver a crear el proyecto con composer y sin embargo sigo con este problema.

He buscado en foros este problema, pero al parecer no existe mucha información del mismo.

Estoy utilizando el acceso de smtp.gmail.com con el puerto 465, y la configuración de sendmail en lugar de smtp.

```
[2018-01-16 21:23:12] local.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Process could not be started [El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
]' in C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:298
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(58): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishProcessConnection()
#1 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(113): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array)
#2 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\SendmailTransport.php(51): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#3 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_SendmailTransport->start()
#4 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(443): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#5 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(217): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#6 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(221): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('email.contact', Array, Object(Closure))
#7 C:\Proyectos\sqn\app\Http\Controllers\MailController.php(29): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#8 C:\Proyectos\sqn\app\Http\Controllers\MailController.php(29): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('email.contact', Array, Object(Closure))
#9 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Mailcontroller->contactMail(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('contactMail', Array)
#12 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(204): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\Mailcontroller), 'contactMail')
#13 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#14 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(572): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#15 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(574): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#36 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(533): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(511): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#54 C:\Proyectos\sqn\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 C:\Proyectos\sqn\public\index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 C:\Proyectos\sqn\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\Proyectos\\sq...')
#57 {main}
```